# Is it possible to create a flutter app that would create and sign cardano transaction

Tags: transaction

I would like to create a simple mobile application using flutter that would create and sign a transaction and submit it through an API like Blockfrost to the network for which it will   interact with a smart contract address.

Is there any supporting library or any approach that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a javascript library (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145501/how-to-use-a-js-library-and-a-js-function-in-a-flutter-mobile-app) then you can try the helios library: https://github.com/Hyperion-BT/Helios

Helios should be callable from within flutter as it doesn't have any dependencies and uses pure javascript (no wasm).

With `helios.js` you can build transactions (https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/building/index.html). Signing however is usually done by a wallet, and for submitting to blockfrost you would have the call the blockfrost endpoint directly.

`helios.js` also allows compiling smart contracts written in the Helios language, but you probably won't be needing that.